# jQuery toggle animation failing only in Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, safari

**JS:**

```
$('.greenBox').hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass('expanded');
    $(this).removeClass('contracted');
}, function(){
    $(this).removeClass('expanded');
    $(this).addClass('contracted');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.expanded {
    height: auto;
    min-height:200px;
    max-height:750px;
    margin-top:5px;
    // to make the box move up add back the bottom 300px
    // bottom: 300px;
    background: linear-gradient(#812990, #9e248e);
    -webkit-transition-timing-function: linear; 
    transition-timing-function: linear; 
}
```

Here is the '`contracted`' class.

```
.contracted {
    max-height: 137px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: Are you using any helper tool, like ReSharper?

Comment: I'll have a check at it tomorrow @ the Office if you haven't gotten an answer by then! ReSharper is great for those kinds of things. Think you can get a free trail month if you check their site.

Comment: I've created this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bellu/ubLd7hsy/ and it works in Safari. Is maybe the .contracted class that creates the problem?

Comment: What is failing? This code works fine for me in Safari. Your question is lacking in clarity. Help us help you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The jQuery is working. The background color is not changing in Safari because you need to use:

```
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#812990, #9E248E);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hsqgqojx/